# How to decompose deep learning trainable parameter into two parts for Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I got this problem when I read the paper 'Federated Semi-Supervised Learning with Inter-Client Consistency & Disjoint Learning'. I am quite wondering about the disjoint learning. The author said 'For a given model, it should decompose into two parts where model = *a* + *b*. When we train the model on dataset A, we only update *a* and hold *b* constant. When we train the model on dataset B, we only update *b* and hold *a* constant.' How can we do this with pytorch?

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: I do not understand precisely how such model should work. Do you input samples from dataset_A into the model A and samples from B to model B ? Or samples from both datasets to both models, but you only train one model at a time (the other one being frozen) ? Can you provide an attempt at implementing what you understand from the paper, we will help you correct what's wrong in the code you get :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the comment. I am sorry for not introduce precisely. There is only one model.  The author decomposes the model parameters θ into two variables, σ and ψ, such that θ = σ + ψ. When training on dataset_A, in model parameters θ, it will only update σ and keep ψ fixed . And when training on dataset_B, in model parameters θ, it will only update ψ and keep σ fixed.

Comment: And up to now, I haven't gotten a clear idea about how to do it in pytorch

Answer (score 0):

Okay it makes more sense now. The use of '+' in the context of hyperparameters do make sense but it was confusing. Anyway, here is how I would do it. Let's make a model which has to successive layers, their weights respectively being σ and ψ (this is a dummy example, don't try to actually train it)

```
class DecomposedModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.layer_A = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.layer_B = nn.Linear(3, 5)

    def forward(self, input_t):
        """ input_t expected shape is (B, 2), output will be (B,5) """
        return self.layer_B(nn.ReLU(self.layer_A(input_t)))

    def parameters_A(self):
        """ returns σ parameters"""
        return self.layer_A.parameters()

    def parameters_B(self):
        """ returns ψ parameters """
        return self.layer_B.parameters()

model = DecomposedModel()
opt_A = Adam(model.parameters_A(), lr=1e-3)
opt_B = Adam(model.parameters_B(), lr=1e-3)
```

With this structure, you can choose to apply `step` on `opt_A` and `opt_B` alternatively, training only one layer at a time
So when you are training on dataset A, you call `opt_A.step()`, and on dataset B you call `opt_B.step()` (with the corresponding calls to `zero_grad` of course)

Answer (score 0):

The paper author's approach: create a custom layer with sigma and phi in two variables.

```py
class CustomLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_shape: int, out_shape: int, supervised: bool):
        super().__init__()

        self.sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(
            in_shape, out_shape), requires_grad=supervised)
        self.phi = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(
            in_shape, out_shape), requires_grad=not supervised)

        self.sigma_bias = nn.Parameter(
            torch.randn(out_shape), requires_grad=supervised)
        self.phi_bias = nn.Parameter(
            torch.randn(out_shape), requires_grad=not supervised)

    def forward(self, X):
        theta = self.phi + self.sigma
        bias = self.phi_bias + self.sigma_bias
        return X @ theta + bias
```

With sigma and phi, you can also use two optimisers to control it instead of the `requires_grad`

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try it